# How to create a regular expression for cricket overs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, requiredfieldvalidator

Please tell me what regular expression should i use to validate cricket overs in textbox.
like it can be 5.1, 5.2,5.3,5.4,5.5 but it should not contain fraction value greater than .5 ,also the values should be numeric only (float and int)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
^[0-9]+(\.(50*|[0-4][0-9]*))?$
```

If you also want fractions like `.2` instead of `0.2`, use this:

```
^[0-9]*(\.(50*|[0-4][0-9]*))?$
```

Explained:

```
^                beginning of the string
[0-9]*           repeat 0 or more digits
(
  \.             match the fraction point
  (
     50*         match .5, or .5000000 (any number of zeros)
     |           or 
     [0-4][0-9]* anything smaller  than .5
  )
)?               anything in this parenthesis is optional, for integer numbers
$                end of the string
```

Your version, `[0-9]+(\.[0-5])?` does not work unfortunately, because, for example `/[0-9]+(\.[0-5])?/.test("0.8")` yields true.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. its working fine but facing issue. its allowing me to enter value like "66.555". as we know the overs should contains 1 value as a fractional value. please provide me this also..

Comment: i altered your expression and found that "[0-9]+(\.[0-5])?" is working fine. please verify that its correct.. thanks

Comment: @Rajesh Rolen- DotNet Developer updated now. It is a bit more complicated, but it should work on virtually everything - `0.5000000`, `0.4999`, `.5`, `5`, etc

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var testString = '5.4';
var regExp = /^\d+(\.[1-5])?$/;
if(regExp.test(testString))
{
 // Do Something
}
</script>
```

Comment: In test matches you have more than 50 overs (grins :)

Comment: Updated the post. If OP can specify what the match format(one day, test, 20-20) I can retrofit it to the same.